# JSON API with live updates stored to firebase db

Tags: android, json, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the title suggests, I have a JSON API that updates every few seconds. I want to add that JSON to my Firebase Database so that I can use it in an android app. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks!

The JSON API contains the FOREX Quotes. It looks something like this:

```
"Time Series (1min)": {
        "2017-08-25 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "72.7850",
            "2. high": "72.8500",
            "3. low": "72.7600",
            "4. close": "72.8200",
            "5. volume": "1687694"
```

As I can't use it directly into my android app, I want to add it into my firebase database first. All I have is the link with the json that updates every few seconds, so after I add them to the firebase db, it should keep updating there too.

Comment: Without knowing more about the technology you've used for your API, and what you've already tried, it'll be hard to help explain your options better than the Firebase documentation does: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new javascript file where I manually took all the quotes from the JSON API, saved them in local variables and stored them in my firebase db.

I hosted the js file on my host and I set it to refresh every 5 seconds.

Works like a charm!